# Export/import Acumatica data contract without API

Tags: serialization, acumatica

Is there any way to export or import data within Acumatica by serializing or deserializing to/from JSON, but without hitting the contract-based API?  In other words, I want to serialize data (e.g. a stock item) based on the data contract, within the same Acumatica instance.  Is the only way to do this to call itself via API, or is there ability to access the querying and serialization which the API performs without the API in the way?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what is your end goal that might help us understand what you are trying to do and help us help you better.

Comment: Also, I just discovered that in a data row's RowPersisted event when the TranStatus is Completed, it still hasn't commited to the db yet.  So if I try to hit the API for the row just "persisted", it returns nothing.

Comment: samol518, I thought my question was pretty clear.  I want to serialize data in the supported data contract format, but without hitting the API.  If you're interested in specifics, I am simply trying to send data (e.g. a stock item and children) to an external queue.  The only way I've found so far is via API hit.  If I try to do this in the RowPersisted event per my  previous comment, the row hasn't even been committed yet, so API call won't even work.

Comment: In RowPersisted are you looking at the event args TranStatus == Completed which should be after the transaction is committed?

Comment: Brendan, yes, as I stated previously.  I just discovered that this doesn't mean it's actually committed.  It must mean that's it's about to be.  I even queried directly in the db, and it's not there until leaving RowPersisted.

Comment: To confirm (because RowPersisted will be called multiple times) you are saying the last time (TranStatus == Completed) the data is not yes in the DB? I would assume this when TranStatus is Open and of course Aborted. I have not tested the point when the data makes it to the database when looking at RowPersisted but thought the last RowPersisted would be available in the database.

Comment: Brendan, yes, this is what I'm saying.  It surprised me also.

Comment: So I was curious and did a little testing on my own. I did find that RowPersisted when e.TranStatus == Completed the value is available in the database. This was only true if there was not another PXTransactionScope wrapped around the persist call. When i wrapped my persist in a PXTransactionScope the value would not be available while in RowPersisted until the transaction scope was complete. Hope that helps some or at least I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to accomplish your task is by overriding the Persist() method in a custom BLC or a BLC extension. After the base method invocation, you should start a background thread by executing PXLongOperation.StartOperation() to serialize the items that you are going to transfer and send them to an external service.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing (overriding Persist()), so that I could call the API after the commit for serialization via data contract.  I wish there were a better way without using the API, which was my original question.  And I'm doing it asynchronously as well so that the persist isn't delayed.  I can't mark this as an answer to my question, but thanks for the input.

Comment: Tony, you don't need to use the C-B API for data serialization. You can obtain all necessary data via data views/caches available in the current BLC or via BQL queries. To my knowledge in .Net there is plenty of different options to serialize class objects to the JSON format.

Comment: Of course the API is not the only way to serialize, but it seems the only way to use the Acumatica data contracts without building JSON from scratch. I started with simple serialization of IBqlTable types, but I couldn't use that object when inserting into a table -- too many errors were being thrown by event handlers and valid data that it considered invalid, so it was fairly useless.  I then had hoped that I could serialize a top level entity and children with Acumatica data contract, but there didn't seem to be a way, so I'm using the API.  A lot of work for something that should be simple.

Comment: new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dacObject)

Comment: HB_ACUMATICA...  Did you even read my posts?  Just serializing a DAC object is not the issue.